# How do I check whether a mockMvc response header is the MD5 representation of a part of my response?

Tags: spring, md5, mockmvc

I need to compare the MD5 hash of a specific value in my mockMvc response body to a header of the same request. I'm not sure how to do this given that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get the content of a jsonPath or xPath matcher. I think something like this is the closest I've managed to get. I'm fairly sure I need to approach this from the header side since MD5 is not easily reversed.

```
mockMvc.perform(get(url)
                .session(session)
                .andExpect(header().string(ETAG,  convertToMD5(jsonPath("$.object.id"))));
```

Is there a way to do this, preferably without writing a custom Matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving deep into the code used by Spring MockMvc, I found that eventually, the `jsonPath().value(Object)` ResultMatcher uses Object.equals() under the hood, and specifically the equals of the `value` parameter. Thus, I've found the easiest way to do this is to write an `MD5Wrapper` class that encapsulates a String object and define a custom equals method that compares the encapsulated String to an MD5 hash of the compared object.

```
public class MD5Wrapper {
    private String mD5Hash;

    public MD5Wrapper(String md5Hash){
        mD5Hash = md5Hash;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o2){
        if(o2 == null && mD5Hash == null){
            return true;
        }       
        if (o2 == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(mD5Hash == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(!(o2 instanceof String)){
            return false;
        }
        return org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex((String)o2).equals(mD5Hash);
    }

    public String getmD5Hash() {
        return mD5Hash;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return mD5Hash;
    }

}
```

Then in the test itself, I retrieved the Etag header I needed, wrapped it and compared it to my ID:

```
ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/projects/1")
    .session(session)
    .contentType(contentTypeJSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .... //various accepts
    ;

MvcResult mvcResult = resultActions.andReturn();
String eTAG = mvcResult.getResponse().getHeader(ETAG);
resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(new MD5Wrapper(eTAG.replace("\"", "")))); //our eTAG header is surrounded in double quotes, which have to be removed.
```

So in the end, I didn't have to approach it from the header side as I originally thought,  but rather from the jsonPath side.